# How to stop two times click event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am working on ajax script, where users can click on add_to_cart button to add items on cart. But unfortunately it adds two clicks on single click.

```
//here is my code
$(".add_to.cart").click(function(e){
  $(this).shoppingCart("add_item");
});
```

this script sends two ajax request on single click..

How to stop it? Thanks for help in advance.

```
//here is my markup
<tr id='p_<?php echo $products['p_id']; ?>'>
   <td class='p-img'><img src='products.php?img=2323' /></td>
   <td class='p-name'><?php echo $products['p_name']; ?></td>
   <td class='p-price'><?php echo $products['p_price]; ?></td>
   <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn_primary add_to_cart'> Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: did you try toggling the .add_to class?

Comment: probably you have bind the event two times in the code. or the same code get executed two times.

Comment: @ArashMilani "or the same code gets executed two times"... His question is to resolve that...

Comment: can you show the relevant markup. Do you have more than one element with the `add_to` and `cart` classes?

Comment: yes i have many buttons with same class..

Comment: It sounds like you have the event handler bound twice. Check to make sure you're not running that `.click` event register more than once or you not binding that handler on a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag with `.data()` checking if it's already been clicked.

```
$('.add_to.cart').click(function(e){
    var el = $(this);

    if(el.data('hasAddedItem') === true)
        return;

    el.data('hasAddedItem', true).shoppingCart('add_item');
});
```

The only potential problem is that you won't be able to re-click it unless you set the element's `hasAddedItem` data back to false.

Comment: Yes, but that literally only executes the callback once. You also cannot unbind it so this solution is more versatile if he wanted to allow the button to be clicked again.

Comment: Regardless, his problem is not with clicking more than once but likely with binding the click event to a parent element as well as the button such that the handler is called twice.

Comment: That's what you are assuming - he needs to provide his HTML structure for us to truly understand why the event is being triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$(".add_to.cart").click(function(e){
```

to

```
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(e){
```

because that is the class you have on the button:

```
class='btn_primary add_to_cart'
```